# ActionListener Event Handling

Tags: java, exception, event-handling, actionlistener

Coded for a checkbox that agrees to the Terms of Service and an accept and decline button.

I need help for an exception handling that

if the user does NOT have the checkbox as SELECTED then when they hit accept, an error message occurs telling the user that he has not selected the checkbox.

How would I code an error handling exception using these 2 arguments?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.lang.Integer.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat.*;

public class JFrameWithPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
    int packageIndex;
    double price;
    double[] prices = {49.99, 39.99, 34.99, 99.99};

    DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
    JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Total Price: "+price);
    JButton button = new JButton("Check Price");
    JComboBox packageChoice = new JComboBox();
    Font newFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    TextField text = new TextField(5);
    JButton accept = new JButton("Accept");
    JButton decline = new JButton("Decline");
    JCheckBox serviceTerms = new JCheckBox("I Agree to the Terms of Service.", false);
    JTextArea termsOfService = new JTextArea("This is a text area", 5, 10);

    public JFrameWithPanel()
    {
        super("JFrame with Panel");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane.add(packageChoice);
        setContentPane(pane);
        setSize(250,250);
        setVisible(true);

        packageChoice.addItem("A+ Certification");
        packageChoice.addItem("Network+ Certification ");
        packageChoice.addItem("Security+ Certifictation");
        packageChoice.addItem("CIT Full Test Package");

        pane.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(text);
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        text.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(termsOfService);
        termsOfService.setEditable(false);
        termsOfService.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        pane.add(serviceTerms);
        serviceTerms.addItemListener(this);

        pane.add(accept);
        accept.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(decline);
        decline.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        packageIndex = packageChoice.getSelectedIndex();
        price = prices[packageIndex];
        text.setText("$"+price);

        Object source = e.getSource();

        if(source == accept)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Thank you for choosing our tests. Enjoy!");
        }
        else if(source == decline)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        int select = e.getStateChange();

        if(select == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please agree to the terms of service.");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Yeah, but the only problem is, how would I make an exception handling alert window (JOptionPane) to tell them to Check the check box to continue yeah.

Comment: Attempted to make an if statement that said if(serviceTerms = false) but it didn't work. Wrong return type.

Comment: Why don't you disable accept when the checkbox is not selected?

Comment: Never thought of that. Gonna try that, hold on.

Comment: Also, you should *not* be using floating point for money. It won't always represent decimal fractions the way you want. You need to use something like `BigDecimal`.

Comment: unexpected type
required: variable
found   : value
   if(serviceTerms.isSelected() = false)
                             ^

Comment: Two things: `isSelected()` already returns a boolean... you don't need to compare it to false, just use `!serviceTerms.isSelected()`. Second, you need to use `==` to check equality; `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: @ColinD +1 I like how you just told him exactly what I answered below. ;) Maybe he'll try it the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check for the isSelected to be true?

```
if (!serviceTerms.isSelected())
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not accepted the terms.");
```

Comment: so if(serviceTerms.isSelected = false){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Must accept.");
}